# Embed JavaScript files inside a .NET class library for Blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Blazor project and I'm trying to move one of the JavaScript files to a class library, I've read the following guides:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl-1
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules

I'm getting the following error:

[image: Browser developer tools]

I'm not sure what I'm missing or what I need to do to get this to work so here is the setup I have:

**Facts:**

1. I'm using `.NET 6`.
2. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac `Version 17.0 Preview (17.0 build 8754)`.
3. The name of the solution is `LinkScreen`.
4. The name of the application project is `Client.Web`.
5. The name of the application assembly is `LinkScreen.Client.Web`.
6. The name of the application default namespace is `LinkScreen.Client.Web`.
7. The hosting model for the application is Web Assembly.
8. The name of the class library project is `Client.BrowserInterop`.
9. The name of the class library assembly is `LinkScreen.Client.BrowserInterop`.
10. The name of the class library default namespace is `LinkScreen.Client.BrowserInterop`.

**Project Structur and Code**

1. Inside the class library I have a script file called `screen-capture.js` under the following directory `wwwroot\scripts` like so:

[image]

The build action for this is set to Content and copy to output directory is set to Do not copy.

2. The class library is referenced to the application like so:

[image]

3. I have a C# class called `ScreenCapture` that wraps the JavaScript module that is the `screen-capture.js` and retuns a reference like so:

```cs
public static async ValueTask<ScreenCapture> CreateAsync(
        IJSRuntime jsRuntime,
        ElementReference videoTagReference)
    {
        var jsModuleRef = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSInProcessObjectReference>("import", "./_content/LinkScreen.Client.BrowserInterop/screen-capture.js").ConfigureAwait(false);

        return new ScreenCapture(jsModuleRef, videoTagReference);
    }
```

Previously I had a reference to the `screen-capture.js` inside `index.html` like so `<script src="_content/LinkScreen.Client.BrowserInterop/scripts/screen-capture.js" type="module"></script>` because I thought it was required to use the `IJSRuntime` methods and then someone on the Blazor channel enlighten me so I removed the reference but I'm still getting the same 404 error now from the wrapper by calling `jsRuntime.InvokeAsync`.

It's important to note that everything works correctly when the script is inside the `wwwroot/scripts` of application folder.

4. My program.cs file is the default for .NET 6 Blazor WebAssembly projects and is like so:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using LinkScreen.Client.Web;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

**Things I've tried and it still doesn't work:**

1. Clean the project, delete the bin and obj directories.
2. Clear the browser's cache as well as disabling it.
3. I've tried both Safari and Chrome but I get the exact same issue.

Comment: Do you get any errors or are there any symptoms (other than "it doesn't work") that may help us identify what the actual issue is?

Comment: @phuzi Updated the post with the error I'm getting.

Comment: Try *deleting the bin and obj folders* then use `<script src="./_content/Client.BrowserInterop/scripts/screen-capture.js />`. Browsers have trouble with modules and I bet your own interop code is calling the functions directly, not trying to import any modules.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually import a module, I'll update the post with current state of project.

Comment: When you used `script type="import"` you were importing the JS file into the script tag, not the global namespace. In your current code you're loading the file stored at `wwwroot/screen-capture.js`. You need to use `./_content/LinkScreen.Client.BrowserInterop/scripts/screen-capture.js` instead. The path `"./_content/Client.BrowserInterop/ScreenCapture.razor.js"` in my question works because the isolated JS file is stored in the same folder as the component at the project root. The compiler uses "magic" to make the JS file appear in the `./_content/Client.BrowserInterop/` path

Comment: Is the blazor app hosted in a net core app?

Comment: @americanslon It's hosted in asp.net core app is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I solved this by following the steps below:

1. Created a new Blazor WebAssembly App with the following options: Configure for HTTPS, ASP.NET Core Hosted and Progressive Web App that generates 3 different projects in .NET 6 Client, Shared and Server.
2. Tested that it works as is and the Server serves the Client.
3. Created a Razor Class Library (RCL) **without** checking the "support pages and views! because it generates something different.
4. Referenced the RCL to the Server project.
5. Created a page on the Client that calls the component that exists in the RCL.
6. And finally it worked!

Now, I think that the reason the component as a library didn't work for my old project are as follows:

- I noticed that the Server didn't serve the Client and the Client was the project that was setup as the Startup project as opposed to the new project that I made.
- I used a regular Class Library and not RCL in the project because I didn't think that there is a difference except the starter files but apparently there is more to it.

Answer (score 8):

I was just trying to export my own components to a library and re-discovered the most important Blazor WASM rule :

- Always clear the Client bin and obj folders.

What worked after copying the folders from the main project to the class library failed after a couple of executions. It seems the `bin` folder still contained some scripts so the paths that worked in the main project kept working until a full clean removed them.

If the script is stored in `wwwroot/scripts` and you use :

```
<script src="./_content/Client.BrowserInterop/scripts/screen-capture.js
```

Your methods should be available globally.

You should consider using JS isolation with side-by-side component scripts to avoid polluting the JS namespace *and* cluttering your `wwwroot` folder.

If your component is names `ScreenCapture.razor`, create a JS module in the same folder named `ScreenCapture.razor.js`. You can load this as a module in your component's `OnAfterRenderAsync` and call its exported methods :

```
private IJSObjectReference? module;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(module ==null)
    {
        var path = "./_content/Client.BrowserInterop/ScreenCapture.razor.js";
        module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", path);
    }
}

    private ValueTask SetTextAsync(string text)
    {
        if (module is null)
        {
            return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
        }
        return module.InvokeVoidAsync("setValue", TextBox, text);
    }
```

**Example**

I was trying to put the code from [this TagSelector component](https://github.com/mwinkler/Blazor.Components/tree/master/src/TagSelectorComponent) into my own RCL library using JS isolation to keep things tidy. The CSS and JS files are stored in `wwwroot` directly so normally I'd have to use :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/MW.Blazor.TagSelector/styles.css" />
<script src="_content/MW.Blazor.TagSelector/interop.js"></script>
```

By renaming the files to `TagSelector.razor.css` and `TagSelector.razor.js` though, I was able to keep them together with the Razor file. I only need to use the `TagSelector` component now. The CSS and JS files are imported automatically.

The JS file was changed to a module :

```
export function getValue(element) {
    return element.value;
}

export function setValue(element, value) {
    element.value = value;
}

export function blur(element) {
    element.blur();
}
```

The module is loaded with :

```
var path = "./_content/MyLibraryName/TagSelector.razor.js";
module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", path);
```

To call the exported `setText` method, the following wrapper is used:

```
    private ValueTask SetTextAsync(string text)
    {
        if (module is null)
        {
            return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
        }
        return module.InvokeVoidAsync("setValue", TextBox, text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();` to your `Program.cs` of the Host Net Core app?

Comment: I tried to add this to the project `builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();` but I get the following error: `Error CS1061: 'WebAssemblyHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WebHost' and no accessible extension method 'WebHost' accepting a first argument of type 'WebAssemblyHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Client.Web)` what assembly do I need to reference or what namespace do I need to add for it to work?

Comment: You are adding it to the client app's `program.cs`. It needs to go into the HOST app's `program.cs`

Comment: Yes I checked and I got it in the host the problem as I describe in the approved answer is that the host did not serve the client to begin with, I think I did some refactoring and things got messed up somewhere so the host wasn't the startup project anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 404 error?
try to modify your script source

```
<script src="_content/LinkScreen.Client.BrowserInterop/scripts/screen-capture.js" type="module"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="./_content/Client.BrowserInterop/scripts/screen-capture.js" type="module"></script>
```

as the offcial document explains:

**The path segment for the current directory (./) is required in order to create the correct static asset path to the JS file.
The {PACKAGE ID} placeholder is the library's package ID.
The package ID defaults to the project's assembly name if  isn't specified in the project file.**

in my case ,it could work afer I modified the source:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah I'm getting 404, I tried this and it doesn't work, unfortunately. I'll update the post with the error I'm getting.

Comment: try to add"./"in front of "_content"

Comment: @EyalAlon, try removing the content part and access it as a normal script. If that doesn't work then try to use js isolation. Where the file is saved as componentName.js

Comment: @Xserge `./_content` is required whether you use a script tag or JS isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I found the issue was different - CORS. I installed a plugin to enable CORS and it worked. Unfortunately the CORS error always showed up *after* showing the javascript (module not found/undefined) making it harder to establish the cause.